# Windows 2003 DNS Zones on Secondary server won't load

Tags: windows, dns

Until recently, we had two Windows 2003 DNS servers (one of the machines recently died, and took the HD's down with it). We're running ok on one, but I'm trying to set up the second.

The server that went down had all the zones as primary, so on the remaining server, I changed them to Primary, and now I'm trying to setup a new server as the secondary to them all (there's around 30 domain names in total, they're not AD integrated)

My problem is that the machine that will now host the secondary copies will not load the data from the other server, and the DNS management console just reads "Zone not loaded by DNS server".

The servers can see each other on the network, and I've tried to sort this myself over the last couple of days (I've only tried to set up two secondaries so far), but to no avail - Any ideas guys?!